# Rails 3 Making a Form with two Models and Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, nested-attributes

What I am trying to do is kinda complicated. Basically I have an order form and my client would like to be able to add and delete fields himself, such as different services you can purchase along with your item. So what I have done is I have made an orders controller and order model along with a field model and fields controller. How would I implement this now? My order model has a `has_many :fields` and my field model has a `belongs_to :order`, but aside from that I am stuck on how to implement this. So far in my orders controller i have a new and create method and heres what inside:

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  #maybe i should put something like: @fields = Field.find(:all)
  @title = "Order Form"
end

def create
  @order = Order.new params[:order]
  if @order.save 
    flash[:notice] = "Your order has been created"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @title = "Order Form"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and in my fields controller I have a show new create edit update functions with nothing in them. What is the best practice to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `nested forms`.

Check two screencasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

It will even answer your need:

> my client would like to be able to add
>   and delete fields himself